# ReplaceAll function in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting a string `"test+test1+asd.txt"` and i want to convert it into `"test test1 asd.txt"`

I am trying to use function `str = str.replace("/+/g"," ");`

but this is not working

regards,
hemant

Comment: Why use a regular expression if it's only one fixed character?

Answer (score 9):

```
str = str.replace(/\+/g," ");
```

Comment: The `+` has special meaning in RegEx. So, you have to escape it with a backslash. That's why S.Mark's RegEx works. `\+`

Comment: And you don't put Regex in strings in Javascript, that is the second reason your replace failed.

Comment: +1 but IMHO needs explanation, like the one from EndangeredMassa :)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for [S.Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830647/replaceall-function-in-javascript/1830660#1830660) if you're intent on using a regular expression, but for a single character replace you could easily use:

```
yourString = yourString.split("+").join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple javascript function that replaces all:

```
function replaceAll (originalstring, exp1, exp2) {
//Replaces every occurrence of exp1 in originalstring with exp2 and returns the new string.

    if (exp1 == "") {
        return;  //Or else there will be an infinite loop because of i = i - 1 (see later).
        }

    var len1 = exp1.length;
    var len2 = exp2.length;
    var res = "";  //This will become the new string

    for (i = 0; i < originalstring.length; i++) {
        if (originalstring.substr(i, len1) == exp1) {  //exp1 found
            res = res + exp2;  //Append to res exp2 instead of exp1
            i = i + (len1 - 1);  //Skip the characters in originalstring that have been just replaced
        }
        else {//exp1 not found at this location; copy the original character into the new string
            res = res + originalstring.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```